# php mysql prepare statement not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm currently learning php and mysql and am trying to build an authentication webpage where the user registers and is able to log in to a member protected page. The registration process works fine but for some reason I'm getting this error in my login execution script.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /homepages/8/d459264879/htdocs/tymbi_reg/login_exec.php on line 40
```

Line 40 is here if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username=? AND password =?"))

I've been trying hard to find where the problem is without any success.

This is the code that I'm using in my login script

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once('connection.php');
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
} else {


    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username=? AND password =?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_results();

        if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
        {

            $SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: home.php");

        }

        else

        {

            $error['alert'] = "Username or password are incorrect";

        }

    }   

}


?>
```

Here's my connection.php code

```
<?php
$con=new mysqli("test","test","test","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

And yes, I have replaced the test values with my details

Comment: are you sure your connection is successfully created?

Comment: I cant see $mysqli connection anywhere

Comment: give var_dump($mysqli) and see what you get?

Comment: I reckon $mysqli is not defined?

Comment: Yes, the connection is included in connection.php

Comment: Then do u mind putting connection.php code in the question section? Let's have a look at that.

Comment: if it is included, doesnt mean it works ... show that part of the code and make sure you print error if it exist.

Comment: You cannot use php variables like this..  is $mysqli global... ?

Comment: you are using `$con` in connection.php and `$mysqli` on other page

Comment: so you have $con in connection.php and use $mysqli in login script?

Comment: just for the same of it, can you tell me what happens when you place the content of connection.php in the code directly without the include? Are the both files in the same directory?

Comment: so I tried var_dump($mysqli) and I get NULL.

Comment: I also replaced $mysqli with $con and the error now is Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::store_results() in /homepages/8/d459264879/htdocs/tymbi_reg/login_exec.php

Comment: yes, both files are in the same directory

Comment: ok all sorted, replaced $con with $mysqli

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have [$mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) defined properly

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','user','pass','database_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `$mysqli` - your connection. That is why it's not working.

Unless it's defined in `connection.php`. Could you try var_dump `$mysqli` and see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

this helps in reading the connection error.

or you can also use

```
try
{
//your connection
}catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend going all-in on using the Mysqli object and not mixing in the procedural functions. You would have caught your error earlier if you had written the connection logic like so:

```
$con = new mysqli("host","user","pass","db");

if ($mysqli->errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

The OP declared the connection as **$con** and later tried to access it as **$mysqli**. mysqli_connect_errno() reports that **$con is ok**, but **$mysqli->errno will fail** because $mysqli is not an object at that point, because he named the the connection $con not $mysqli

Comment: What's wrong with catching errors with mysqli_connect_errno()? Any reason it should fail the OP where your code would report?

Comment: It's not that it's wrong per se. It answers the wrong question.